# Running an "is all of" filter on a field collection

Tags: views, entities

I'm currently working with a field collection lets call it Certificates. Certificates contains the following fields... Certificate Type, Certificate Number, Expiration Date, Etc.
I have a content type called Applicant that contains the field collection Certificates. Ideally, I'm trying create a view that allows for a "is all of" filter for the various certificates. We are trying to filter candidates by multiple certificates at the same time. To complicate this further, I've been asked to do this in a single multiselect drop down using chosen. By adding the field-collection as a relationship, I am able to add a Chosen multiselect that works correctly with the "is one of" operator, but it won't work with the "is all of". I think that the reason for this is that it seems like the certificate type is overriding the actual field-collection in order to display the certificate. Looking for suggestions. Any help will be greatly appreciated!!!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have a solution that's a bit of a work around, but seems to work fine. I ended up using the same relationship multiple times and increasing the delta value by 1 with each new relationship which pulled in each option in the subcategory (think first field in the field collection). I then grouped the fields and used a combine filter to run the "is all of" search. Seems to work great and isn't overly resource intensive. This will give you a 1 to 1 result based on whatever is in the the field collection field item you build the relationship off of.

Hope this helps.

Best,
Shawn